# Django: creating number of forms dynamically

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

so I want to create a dynamic number of forms depending on a variable.

Here is my forms.py

```
class CTestform(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, c_test_tokens, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CTestform, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        wordsbeforegap = ''
        iteratorforgaps = 0

        for i in (0, len(c_test_tokens)-1):
            if '#GAP#' not in c_test_tokens[i]:
                wordsbeforegap = wordsbeforegap + c_test_tokens[i]

            else:
                self.fields[iteratorforgaps] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': '5'}),
                                                    required=False, label=wordsbeforegap, label_suffix='')
                wordsbeforegap = ''
                iteratorforgaps += 1
```

Here is my views.py where I call CTestform to render:

```
def ctest(request):
    # this function is not really important for the question
    # c_test_tokens = list of chars
    c_test_tokens, gaps, tokenindexe = generate_c_test(exampletext())

    form = CTestform(c_test_tokens=c_test_tokens)
    return render(request, 'ctest.html', {'form': form})
```

I thought that the forms created would be in self.fields, so to print the forms at my website I have in my template this:

```
<div class="ctest">
    {%  for forms in form.fields %}
        {{ forms }}
        {%  endfor %}
    </div>
```

But the site is empty and no forms are getting rendered. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**:

Problem was in my for loop

Missed "range" lol

```
for i in range (0, len(c_test_tokens)-1):
```

Comment: you could write: `for i in range(len(c_test_tokens)):` or just for `c in c_test_tokens:` if you aren't using the index.